# Switching a VM to/from LAN when Cisco AnyConnect is disconnected/reconnected

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, nat, bridge

## Question

Here is my current setup (refer to the diagram below): Within my local LAN, call that LAN1, I have a Windows 10 Enterprise laptop called host2. Within host2 I have running VMware Workstation 15 Player (15.5.1 build-15018445) that is managing a VM running Ubuntu 19.10 called host1.  Also inside LAN1 I have another Ubuntu 19.10 machine (a real machine, not a VM) called host3 that I should be able to access via "host3.local" from either host2 or host1.  On host2 I also have installed Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client that I use to enable connection from host1 or host2 to yet another Linux machine running within a different LAN (call that LAN2).

I believe, from reading [How to create a split tunnel VPN on OSX for Cisco VPN client?](https://superuser.com/q/44612/106977), that it is impossible, without system administrator involvement, in my configuration, to have all hosts configured so that host1 can access both host3 and host4 at the very same time.  So that is not my question.

When I disconnect Cisco AnyConnect, and then want to connect from host1 to host3, I have to navigate through menus on the VM Player to manually switch from NAT to Bridged+"Replicate Physical Connection State" each time (see diagram below for the screenshots).  And I have to do the reverse switching after I have reconnected AnyConnect again. And in certain circumstances (under **Bridging conditions** below) I *also* have to disconnect and reconnect the network adapter on VMware Player in order for it to fully switch between those two modes.  All of that, as you can imagine, is too painful to have to do manually, *repeatedly*.

How do I streamline that activity so that I don't have to do that manually each time AnyConnect is disconnected or reconnected? And by streamline, acceptable answers are a script or DOS Batch file I can execute on host2 (perhaps via a shortcut on the Win10 desktop) or on host1 after I disconnect/reconnect AnyConnect.

## Diagram

[image]

## Detailed results under NAT conditions

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client: Connected
On host1:

Before disconnecting and reconnecting:

1. ping host3.local --> FAIL: ping: host3.local: Name or service not known
2. ping host4: PASS

After disconnecting and reconnecting:

1. ping host3.local --> FAIL: ping: host3.local: Name or service not known
2. ping host4: PASS

## Detailed results under Bridging conditions:

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client: Connected
On host1:

Before disconnecting and reconnecting:

1. ping host3.local --> FAIL: ping: host3.local: Name or service not known
2. ping host4 --> FAIL: ping: host4: Temporary failure in name resolution

After disconnecting and reconnecting:

1. ping host3.local --> PASS
2. ping host4 --> FAIL: ping: host4: Temporary failure in name resolution